# How can I find an input element of multple classes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, frontend

I know that for multple classes I can look for $(".form-group.text-center") my question is how can I find an input element that is inside of the conjuction of these 2 classes

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <label class="label-text no-padding"></label>
    <input class="bg-color form-control mfa" placeholder="Answer" type="TEXT">
</div>
```

Comment: Please shar your HTML and then elaborate your question to make it clear. Also add the code what you tried so far to achieve your goal.

Comment: `$(".form-group.text-center input")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:-

```
$(".form-group.text-center input")
```

***Demo example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form-group.text-center input").on('mouseout',function(){
   alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group text-center">
  <label class="label-text no-padding"></label>
  <input class="bg-color form-control mfa" placeholder="Answer" type="TEXT">

</div>
```

***Note:- based on yout HTML structure you can go for these options also:-***

```
$(".form-group.text-center .mfa")
$(".form-group.text-center input[type='text']")
$(".form-group.text-center input[type=text]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()` method:

```js
$(".form-group.text-center").find("input").addClass("border")
```

```css
.border{
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group text-center">
  <label class="label-text no-padding"></label>
  <input class="bg-color form-control mfa" placeholder="Answer" type="TEXT">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(".form-group.text-center > input")` like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form-group.text-center > input").on('mouseout',function(){
  input = $(this);// $(this) means your selected object -the input-
  input.val("i am an input !!");
   alert(input.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group text-center">
  <label class="label-text no-padding"></label>
  <input class="bg-color form-control mfa" placeholder="Answer" type="TEXT">

</div>
```

the `>` means the direct child